# Cant start a pythonscript from systemd service

Tags: python, python-3.x, systemd

Here is the my systemd unit file. I have a logging init script inside pythonscript. Here happened a filenot found error. At the same time it seems the python is from system python directory and not from my environment. how to solve this.

```
[Service]
User=nobody
Group=nogroup
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/app/env/bin/python /home/ubuntu/app/backend/app.py --path=/tmp/app_1.sock
```

Systemd error log:

```
:     loghandler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('logs/mainserver.log', when="midnight", i
:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/handlers.py", line 202, in __init__
:     BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, filename, 'a', encoding, delay)
:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/handlers.py", line 57, in __init__
:     logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1032, in __init__
:     StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1061, in _open
:     return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/logs/mainserver.log'
```

Also please tell from which directory my script is running..

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding directive in `[Service]` part

```
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/app/backend/
```

This is working without any errors. I think now python env is used from my `aioenv`. Otherwise it aready should show some erros. Also keep in mind `do not put` the `WorkingDirectory` before `ExecStart=`
Hope this will help someone